# Access JSON Object in array

Tags: json

Hi I'm trying to do some charting with Google Analytics and I can get the data into JSON but I get stuck from there, this is the json as seen in firebug.

```
{"total_results":1,"rows":[[7861]],"column_headers":[{"dataType":"INTEGER","columnType":"METRIC","name":"ga:visits"}]}
```

So I'm trying to extract the fact that gavisits has 7842 results for the last 30 days, this is my code

```
$.getJSON(
"https://api.oocharts.com/v1/query.jsonp?" //note the 'jsonp' return type
+ "query=" + "visits-by-date-cg"
+ "&key=" + "myapikey here"
+ "&start=" + "30d" //30 days from current date
+ "&callback=?"
, null, function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

How do I loop through the 'data' to get 7842 so that I can store this as a variable?

Thank you

Comment: The thing you posted above doesn't look like a JSON. Do console.log(JSON.stringify(json))

Comment: Yeah, that's not JSON.

Comment: thanks man, the JSON.stringify gave me a more legible output, I have updated the result above

Comment: McGarnagle that did the trick without me having to use JSON.stringify, nice work, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find `7842` anywhere in that object, but there is a property called `rows` containing an array with one value, which itself is an array with one value, which is `7861`. That's probably what you're looking for:

```
data.rows[0][0]
```

Comment: yes sorry 7861 is what I was looking for. Thanks for the correct answer